# 'sam local invoke -d' debug session does not exit in command prompt

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I use the command `sam local invoke 'functionName' -d 5858` to debug lambda function locally in terminal/cmd window with VSCode (The terminal is open in a separate window, not in VSCode). The problem I am facing is that the the debug session does not exit in terminal/cmd when I press CTRL+C (or any other exit method). The only way I can exit the session is by starting the debugger in VSCode and then click on `disconnect` the debugger from within VSCode. I am not sure if this issue occurs for everyone.

Is there any way I can directly end the session from terminal/cmd without having to start the debugger in VSCode?

Here is the link to AWS Docs which has the steps to debug lambda functions locally:
[Step-through debugging Lambda functions locally](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging.html)

Comment: Run it outside of VSCode - does it exit then?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I am running it outside VSCode, in a separate Terminal window.

Comment: "locally in terminal/powershell/cmd with VSCode"?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I am debugging lambda function in VSCode, but the terminal is open in a separate window (Not in VSCode). I'll update the question with this.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. CTRL-C does not work to stop the debugging session

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker Desktop, go to Docker Desktop UI and locate the running container in the Containers menu. You can stop the container using the Stop icon. This will free your terminal.